# Does splitting up one-liners cause more overhead?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work out how people feel about one-liners, compared to splitting statements into multiple lines.

For example, this C# code:

```
var output = Regex.Match(key, @"\[(.*?)\]").Groups[1].Value;
```

could just as easily be written like this:

```
var regex = @"\[(.*?)\]";
var matches = Regex.Match(input, regex);
var output = matches.Groups[1].Value;
```

Does the 2nd snippet have extra overheads to it? Or does the compiler basically turn both snippets into the same code in the end?

Obviously, the 2nd snippet is easier to step-thru debug, but it also annoys me that it takes up 3 lines for some relatively simple code.

Comment: seems opinion based and can depend on who else will look at the code. Second one results in 2 `stloc.0` IL instructions more, but that doesn't really matter ..

Comment: Those variables do in fact exist, they just don't have a name.  In the Release build those variables disappear as well.  So no difference.  Not just a debugging problem btw, a runtime exception gets harder to diagnose as well.  You can guess at the cause of the IndexOutOfRangeException here, but NullReferenceException gets to be a headache in fluent style.  YMMV, you'll inevitably learn your style preference in the school of hard knocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you have optimizations turned on (i.e. Debug or Release build).

In unoptimized builds, the compiler will try to keep as many locals (often variables in a method, like `regex` or `matches`, but the compiler can add more as temporary storage if necessary) for easier debugging. The optimizer (used in Release builds) will try to optimize those away whenever it can. That's also why you can't inspect some variables when debugging an optimized assembly.

Let's use the [online C# compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgHQBUCmAPYqBKmA5gK4QCGATgKLYAOlmAzk2APYB2TA3ALABQAmAGYkAJgQBhBAG8BCBUlEwALAgCyyABQpEAa0wBPAJTzFc/oqsIAblQRsSwOk4QBeBISI5U68sABjAAstA0MAGiQYACIAHQBtLVQAKgB+Y1iAXWjjVABxSkc6JnjkTNQANXIIEkw+S0UAXzMFFqUkNXUxHWREMA4XYFMGhQtrRTtKBEZvbHcouMSU9Kzo+vGFSYQAW39g5nmvHz9AkP7ByJmcY3WNrcdnVw9d0+Z8wpJi0vKqmrq25r8RpAA) to convert the code into IL.

One-liner, Debug:

```
.locals init (
    [0] string
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: ldstr "\\[(.*?)\\]"
IL_0007: call class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Match(string, string)
IL_000c: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match::get_Groups()
IL_0011: ldc.i4.1
IL_0012: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection::get_Item(int32)
IL_0017: callvirt instance string [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture::get_Value()
IL_001c: stloc.0
IL_001d: ret
```

One-liner, Release:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1
IL_0001: ldstr "\\[(.*?)\\]"
IL_0006: call class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Match(string, string)
IL_000b: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match::get_Groups()
IL_0010: ldc.i4.1
IL_0011: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection::get_Item(int32)
IL_0016: callvirt instance string [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture::get_Value()
IL_001b: pop
IL_001c: ret
```

Long method, Debug:

```
.locals init (
    [0] string,
    [1] class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match,
    [2] string
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldstr "\\[(.*?)\\]"
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldarg.1
IL_0008: ldloc.0
IL_0009: call class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Match(string, string)
IL_000e: stloc.1
IL_000f: ldloc.1
IL_0010: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match::get_Groups()
IL_0015: ldc.i4.1
IL_0016: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection::get_Item(int32)
IL_001b: callvirt instance string [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture::get_Value()
IL_0020: stloc.2
IL_0021: ret
```

Long method, Release:

```
.locals init (
    [0] string
)

IL_0000: ldstr "\\[(.*?)\\]"
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldarg.1
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: call class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Match(string, string)
IL_000d: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match::get_Groups()
IL_0012: ldc.i4.1
IL_0013: callvirt instance class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection::get_Item(int32)
IL_0018: callvirt instance string [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Capture::get_Value()
IL_001d: pop
IL_001e: ret
```

In Release builds, the code is nearly identical. The compiler introduces only one local for the longer method, a `string`, which contains the regex. The one-liner has no locals.
The compiler didn't generate a local for the return value for either function.

In Debug builds, the one-liner only has a local to hold the return value. The longer method has locals for all three variables.

That's just the generated IL, though. The runtime/JIT compiler will perform some more optimizations. You most likely won't gain any speed benefits by inlining the locals by hand.
And in this particular case, most Regex operations are probably orders of magnitude more expensive than storing two locals on the stack anyway, so pick whatever style you like more.

Comment: IT might be good to have your IL comparisons in the answer itself - it would be much easier to read since this is a large part of your answer and I don't know if sharplab will necessarily keep that around (or be around) forever in which case this answer might become invalid after some time!

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, splitting up statements is a matter of personal choice. Statements like these:

```
public static void main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(“hello world”);
}
```

Is interpreted by the compiler same as (whitelines, spaces are ignored)

```
public static void main()
{ Console.WriteLine(“hello world”); }
```

Obviously the first one is more readable.

An object will still be stored on the heap whether its on one line or different lines.

A readable, testable, maintainable code is more important than slight cost of performance with machines getting faster and faster.

This is more readable;

```
if (i == j ||
    j == k ||
    l == m)
{

}
```

Same like:

```
 var result = list
               .Where(x => x == some Variable)
               .Skip(5)
               .ToList();
```

There are guidelines which state that a method shouldnt be more than 7 lines.

In short, I feel that a debuggable code is more important.